# How to install wkhtmltoimage on a linux based web server

Tags: php, wkhtmltoimage

I just want to know how to install wkhtmltoimage into my Linux shared hosting server. I am newbie and dont how to start doing this. Can anyone explain step by step.

Comment: I don't think that shared hosting gives you permissions to compile programs. Upgrade to a dedicated server.

Comment: There is library fully writed in php called [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) that gives you possibilities to write html in a pdf file. [Exemple](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf)

Comment: But i wanted to get a screenshot of a website by its URL

Comment: You should be able to simply drop the *precompiled binaries provided by the project onto the server*, set appropriate permissions, and invoke them from PHP...

Answer (score -1):

Okay there is web service called [GrabzIt](http://grabz.it/api/php/).
Check it out !

You

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887).